# Why can't Wolfram calculate the Laplace transform of $\sinh(t)\sin(t)$ correctly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, wolfram-alpha

## Question

Show that the Laplace transform of $\sinh(t)\sin(t) = \frac{2s}{s^4+4}$.

Wolfram can't calculate this as is, so I tried to simplify it a bit. I defined  $\sinh(t)$ as $e^t-e^{-t}$ and split up the operation. This is what Wolfram outputs (after I pair them up myself):

$$
\frac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}-\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}
$$

However, when you attempt to structure this to show that it answers the question, you get

$$
\frac{4s}{s^4+4}
$$

Why is it not calculating this correctly? How do you solve this problem then?

Comment: Because the answer you gave may be wrong? Never underestimate the probability of the book being wrong.

Comment: @FundThmCalculus I've been assuming that probability is close to zero my whole life. I also don't think the $\frac{2s}{s^4+4}$ is wrong. We asked our teacher about it and he looked it over and hinted that there is a way, we just haven't found it. I was like....alright....

Comment: if your teacher hinted it was right, he's probably right. I have had a number of typographical errors that give wrong answers in my mathematics and physics textbooks, so I am always somewhat suspicious of book answers. I didn't realize that the $\sinh t$ definition was incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note how you have defined $\sinh(t)$. A factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is missing, which when you correct for should give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Oh wow.....Thank you so much! That was it! You are magic!